# How to addEventListener to multiple repeated divs

Tags: javascript

I am working on some kind of humburger menu, one page could have more than 1 hamburger menu, so if i click any of the div it should open the menu for me.

for example
in same page if i click on button one it should open menu for me, if i can click on button two it should open menu for me and so on ...

so far i try this, it only worked for the first div and the rest of the div doesn't work, any help please?

```
var kebab = document.querySelectorAll('.kebab'),
            dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');

        kebab.forEach(element => {
            element.addEventListener('click', function() {
                dropdown.classList.toggle('hidden');
                dropdown.classList.remove('block');
            })
        })
```

**My html code**

so each parent div has `.kebab` if i click on `.kebab` div it should open `.dropdown` div and so on ...

```
<div class="1">
<div class="kebab">
<div class="dropdown hidden">
<div class="kebabmenu ">
 <a href="">Preview Invoice</a>
<a href="">Download Invoice</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="1">
<div class="kebab">
<div class="dropdown hidden">
<div class="kebabmenu ">
 <a href="">Preview Invoice</a>
<a href="">Download Invoice</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the problem lies behind your logic. For each of the elements that you are adding a listener, you are manipulating the dropdown variable, which is a same element every time.

Comment: @MohammadMahdiMohajer could you please correct the code, i have try everything but doesn't work. than you.

Comment: It really depends on the logic. Idk what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Are you trying to open the same menu from multiple buttons or a different menu for each button? Also, removing class block may be an issuse because you're not getting it back as in a `toggle`.

Comment: @Gary i just update the question

Comment: @MohammadMahdiMohajer i just update the question could you please look at it now.

Comment: Your using `querySelectorAll` to get all the `.kebab` elements but only `querySelector` to find the  first `.dropdown`. You need to connect the dropwdon to the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @ppower mentioned, you are targeting all burger menus to a single dropdown. In your nested structure you can rewrite the code like this:

```
var kebab = document.querySelectorAll(".kebab");

kebab.forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var dropdown = element.querySelector(".dropdown");

    dropdown.classList.toggle("hidden");
    dropdown.classList.remove("block");
  });
});
```

it'll find a dropdown inside that particular clicked .kebab and toggle it.
Hope this helps.
[codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-bassi-3igupy?file=/src/index.js)

#### === Update ===

Answering your question on how to close a dropdown on click outside — I'd go with a generic click listener on the page and calculate if its target or parent is a burger menu or not

```
document.addEventListener("click", handleDocumentClick);

function handleDocumentClick(event) {
  const clickedElement = event.target;
  const isKebabClick = clickedElement.matches(".kebab");
  if (isKebabClick) {
    const dropdown = clickedElement.querySelector(".dropdown");
    dropdown.classList.toggle("hidden");
    return;
  }

  // close all dropdowns if the click happens outside kebab
  if (!clickedElement.closest(".kebab")) {
    const allDropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown");
    allDropdowns.forEach((dropdown) => {
      dropdown.classList.add("hidden");
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help, that's exactly what i was looking for, is it possible to close the div clicking on outside of the div, like a model when you click on anything outside of modal it closed.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet might illustrate the point.

```js
var kebab = document.querySelectorAll('.kebab');

kebab.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    evt.currentTarget.firstElementChild.classList.toggle('hidden');

  })
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.kebab {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.kebab>.dropdown {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="1">
  <div class="kebab">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="kebabmenu ">
        <a href="">Preview Invoice</a>
        <a href="">Download Invoice</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="1">
  <div class="kebab">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="kebabmenu ">
        <a href="">Preview Invoice</a>
        <a href="">Download Invoice</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, although you're not asking this, you don't need to have a listener on every menu button. One method to reduce the number of listener is illustrated in this snippet. It may seem a bit odd at first but when you start to have many active elements with listeners, this approach can be helpful. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56094898/how-to-test-html-elements-for-unique-identity-without-assigning-an-id) to one of my old questions may provide a better explanation.

```js
// This can be on any parent element; doesn't have to
// be as high up the DOM as the body element.

document.body.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false)

function handleClick(event) {
  let evt = event.target;
  if (evt.matches('.kebab, .kebab *')) {
    while (evt && !evt.matches('.kebab')) {
      evt = evt.parentNode;
    }
    showMenu(evt.firstElementChild);
  } else if ( evt.matches('.otherClass') ) {
    /* test and invoke another function to handle specific event. */
  }
}

function showMenu(menu) {
  menu.classList.toggle('hidden'); 
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.kebab {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.kebab>.dropdown {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="1">
  <div class="kebab">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="kebabmenu ">
        <a href="">Preview Invoice</a>
        <a href="">Download Invoice</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="1">
  <div class="kebab">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="kebabmenu ">
        <a href="">Preview Invoice</a>
        <a href="">Download Invoice</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```